# xunit.net - Why not use a static constructor instead of IClassFixture for shared state?

Tags: unit-testing, xunit.net

According to the [xunit.net documentation](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context), if you want to share state between tests, you are supposed to create an object T that implements IDisposable and does the buildup/teardown and then derive your class from IClassFixture.

Is there any particular reason I should go to all this trouble? Wouldn't it be simpler to just give the class a static constructor and do the buildup there?

I realize I don't get teardown.  But this is shared state; Once my tests are done, the app exits.  That's all the teardown I need.

Is there any other downside to this?